# The Cantor's set is uncountable

Tags: cardinals, cantor-set

To show that the Cantor's set, $K$, is uncountable we consider the following function
\begin{equation}
f\colon K\to [0,1]
\end{equation}
if $f$ is surjective, then the cardinality of $[0,1]$ can not be higher than that of $K$, however $K\subset[0,1]$, then they have the same cardinality.

Now, $x\in K$ if and only if $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}$, where $a_k\in\{0,2\}$.

Now, let $x\in K$, then
\begin{equation}
x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}
\end{equation}
if we replace every number $2$ with the number $1$ and consider the new number in basis $2$, we get a new number of $[0,1]$. At this point my book states that $f$ is surjective. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: "... the follwing function"??? What is $f$? We can all guess, but nobody's going to explain this until you tell us what $f$ _is_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every element $x$ of $[0,1]$ can be expressed in binary:$$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{b_n}{2^n}.$$Therefore,$$x=f\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2b_n}{3^n}\right).$$